# Subcomputation in MonadState with a Lens

Tags: haskell, state-monad

Is it possible to create a function:

```
liftState :: (MonadState s ms, MonadState t mt) => Lens' s t -> mt a -> ms a
```

That, given a `Lens' s t` that can get and set a `t` inside an `s`, lifts a `MonadState` computation with state `t` into a `MonadState` computation with state `s`?

How would one go about running a subcomputation over a different state type?

Comment: You seem to be looking for [`zoom` from `Control.Monad.Zoom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#t:Zoom).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm after!

Answer (score 3):

General note: it's seldom a good idea to use `Lens` / `Getter` / `Prism'` etc. as the argument type for functions. Keep in mind that those are really universally-quantified types (in `lens`, Van Laarhoven types `∀ f . (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`), so functions accepting them are rank-2 polymorphic, which is quite a pain for the type checker. Instead, you should use one of the *concrete* optic types, which are in the `lens` library prefixed with the letter `A`. I.e. you want to make it

```
liftState :: (MonadState s ms, MonadState t mt) => ALens' s t -> mt a -> ms a
```

Though as duplode already commented that you should really just use [`zoom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#t:Zoom) for this, it's also not difficult to implement this less generic version yourself:

```
liftState l m = state $ \s -> case runState m $ s ^# l of
                           (a, b) -> (a, s & l #~ b)
```

Here, [`^#` and `#~`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-94--35-) are basically the same as the better known `^.` and `.~` operators, except those actually want `AGetter` and `ASetter`, respectively. (Which is compatible with `Lens'`, but not with `ALens'`; in more complicated functions you could always get around this issue by using [`cloneLens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:cloneLens)).